# Inject class in custom Field

Tags: magento2, extensions, dependency-injection, custom-field

I created a backend configuration for my custom plugin

> /app/code/Sostanza/LiveHelp/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

https://pastebin.com/2jwnYLwb

> /app/code/Sostanza/LiveHelp/Block/Button.php

https://pastebin.com/myadtSZE

I need to get the value of a saved option and I already have a Helper class where I can read the value I need.

I have my helper in

> /app/code/Sostanza/LiveHelp/Helper/Data.php

https://pastebin.com/JAUWX41c (Max 2 links with my reputation)

But if in the Button.php I add

```
Sostanza\LiveHelp\Helper\Data $data
```

The config section doesn't get rendered anymore
I tried also to inject other stuff, but it doesn't work.
Of course I ran "magento setup:upgrade" and deleted cache/generation folders.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your code look like this:

```
protected $_helper;

public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Sostanza\LiveHelp\Helper\Data $helper,
            array $data = []
    ) {
     $this->_helper = $helper;
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

And then you can use functions in your helper class like this:

```
$this->_helper->someRandomFunction();
```

So in general: you need to pass your helper into __construct() method, then you can use it.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I sayd that if I add that code into my class, it doesn't work!

Comment: Wait, you injected Helper before array $data. That I haven't tried yet. I'll let you know, maybe the issue is caused by wrong order

Comment: I can't believe this. It was the order...but why? If the parent class wants $context and $data why inject in different order?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried it with "\" in the beginning of "\Sostanza\LiveHelp\Helper\Data" ? Because it make a lot of difference.

Comment: Sorry, i can't comment to above answer

Comment: And yes, it was me, who answered.

Comment: Yes I tried that. But it broke anyway...I'll give another try..Anyway I also tried with "use \Sostanza\LiveHelp..." and "use Sostanza\LiveHelp..."

Comment: I confirm that it doesn't work either with or without "\" if $data is before...I really don't understand...

Comment: Weird, I'm not sure if it's all about order. Maybe you was not paying attention about something :)

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad that I helped.

Comment: Too bad that I wasn't logged in. this is my first answer here :)

Comment: Yep, I'm better in Javascript and other stuff, I reached 1000 reputation on stackoverflow (other account).